# MongoDB replica set on a single machine for better reads?

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have a single mongod (2.0.2) running on a (Intel Xeon 8 core 2.1 Ghz, 32 GB RAM) server. Here are some sample stats from mongostat (usual normal calm day):

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults locked % idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn repl       time
 0    186      3      0       0       5       0  42.6g  87.8g  22.6g      2      0.8          0       0|0     0|0    35k     1m   319    M   20:36:00
 0    177      3      0       0       4       0  42.6g  87.8g  22.5g      2      0.7          0       0|0     0|0    28k   993k   319    M   20:36:30
 0    181      3      0       0       3       0  42.6g  87.8g  22.6g      1      0.6          0       0|0     0|1    28k   878k   319    M   20:37:00
 0    177      4      0       0       4       0  42.6g  87.8g  22.6g      2      0.7          0       0|0     0|0    31k   851k   319    M   20:37:30
 0    171      2      0       0       3       0  42.6g  87.8g  22.6g      2      0.4          0       0|0     1|0    25k   912k   319    M   20:38:00
 0    133      1      0       0       3       0  42.6g  87.8g  22.5g      0      0.3          0       0|0     0|0    20k   673k   319    M   20:38:30
 0    180      3      0       0       4       0  42.6g  87.8g  22.5g      1      0.6          0       0|0     1|0    29k   890k   319    M   20:39:00
```

But sometimes when there are 500-600 users online (I store visit counters in Mongo, so there are a lot of updates when visitors come) queries jump up to ~500 per second and read queue grows quickly and stays at around 40-50 for few minutes which makes scripts time out.

Can adding a replica set member on the same machine (I don't have any more physical servers) help me? I want to set the read preference to point to the secondary member so that writes on the primary instance do not block the reads.

Comment: writes on the primary instance are also written on the secondary instances so I don't think that adding secondaries improves read performance.

Comment: the manual says that replica sets may improve read scaling but that would depend on exactly what is happening with the application. reads from the secondaries may lag behind the primary which may be a problem with certain applications. mongo has a single global lock for each db so don't write visit counters to the same database as your business data to avoid contention. as this question is a month old any update on what happened next?